# a component in windows live messenger in flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, icons, drop-down-menu

in windows live messenges the status setting component tht is an icon, label and a dropdown arrow. on rollover it gives u border around the component, how to implement the same in air application using flex.
i got this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd570146.aspx but how to implement it in flex?
thanks in advance.
bagi

Answer (score 0):

Use a ComboBox with an itemRenderer.  Although, you're going to have trouble displaying an image in the "Input" piece of the drop down.

Comment: actually im working on air. i can do it with poping up the native menu , but im unable to add icon to nativemenu items , nor able to style the items. Not able to change the rollover color, text color and all. any work around to achieve this. icons and styling is must.

Comment: Correct, I believe you cannot add styling or icons to the NativeMenu.  Some "non-AIR" programs do seem to support that, but I'm unaware of any AIR support for such things.